# Hadoop Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when calling hdfsOpenFile in hdfs C API

Tags: apache, hadoop, java-native-interface, hdfs, libhdfs

Firstly I had the hadoop-2.7.2 built using mvn and environment variables set correctly. Then I'm trying to run the simple example on Apache website: [C API libhdfs example code](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html)

```
#include "hdfs.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
  const char* writePath = "/tmp/testfile.txt";
  hdfsFile writeFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, writePath, O_WRONLY |O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
  if(!writeFile) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", writePath);
      exit(-1);
  }
  char* buffer = "Hello, World!";
  tSize num_written_bytes = hdfsWrite(fs, writeFile, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
  if (hdfsFlush(fs, writeFile)) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to 'flush' %s\n", writePath);
      exit(-1);
  }
  hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
}
```

Then I got the error message as below:

> $ could not find method create from class org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem with signature (Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/permission/FsPermission;ZISJILorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream;
>
> $ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: create
>
> $ Call to org.apache.hadoop.conf.FileSystem::create((Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/permission/FsPermission;ZISJILorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream;) failed!

But I do can find the 'create' function in org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem:
[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem function list](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/index.html?org%2Fapache%2Fhadoop%2Ffs%2FFileSystem.html)

Anyone have idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit my silly question here. I included a wrong dependency in my linking definition. So my program is trying to call a wrong create() from another library... 
Now I'm able to use all the open sourced hdfs API now.